# Array.includes() to find object in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm attempting to find an object in an array using `Array.prototype.includes`. Is this possible? I realize there is a difference between shallow and deep comparison. Is that the reason the below code returns false? I could not find a relevant answer for `Array.includes()`.

[image: dev tools console]

Comment: because `{a: 'b'} == {a: 'b'}` is `false`?

Comment: Yes, you can use Array.prototype.includes to find an object in an array, but it must be the exact same object, not a newly created object like your screenshot shows. This works: `const a = {}; console.log( [a].includes( a ) );`.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

`Array.includes` compares by object identity just like `obj === obj2`, so sadly this doesn't work unless the two items are references to the same object. You can often use [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead which takes a function:

```js
const arr = [{a: 'b'}]
console.log(arr.some(item => item.a === 'b'))
```

But of course you then need to write a small function that defines what you mean by equality.

Comment: If my object is like {a: 'b',b:'c'}, how I'm supposed to compare to be sure it's the same object? Some function tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test...

Comment: @probitaille, you need a function that compares objects the way you want, then use that for the comparison instead of `==`. There options for that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript

Comment: `Array#includes` actually uses the same-value-zero equality algorithm.

Comment: Interesting @iota. Are there any examples where  `a === b` and same-value-zero equality are different in this context (other than maybe NaN)?

Answer (score 9):

Its' because both of the objects are not the same. Both are stored at different place in memory and the equality operation results `false`.

But if you search for the same object, then it will return `true`.

[image]

Also, have a look at the below code, where you can understand that two identical objects also results `false` with the `===` operator.

For two objects to return `true` in `===`, they should be pointing to same memory location.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is because the `includes` checks to see if the object is in the array, which it in fact is not:

```
> {a: 'b'} === {a: 'b'}
false
```

This is because the test for equality is not testing if the objects are the same, but whether the point to the same object. Which they don't.

Answer (score 4):

You are on the right track but, the issue is the difference between reference and value types, you currently are using a reference type (object literal), so when you compare what is in the array with what you have, it will compare the references and not the values. this is what I mean:

```js
    var ar = [];
    var x = {a: "b", c: "d" };
    ar.push(x);

    // this will log true because its the same reference
    console.log("should be true: ", ar[0] === x);

    ar.push({a: "b", c: "d" });
    // this will log false because i have created 
    // a different reference for a new object.
    console.log("should be false: ", ar[1] === x);
    
    // Think of it like this
    var obja = { foo: "bar" }; // new reference to 'obja'
    var objb = { foo: "bar" }; // new reference to 'objb'
    var valuea = 23;
    var valueb = 23;
    
    // 'obja' and 'obja' are different references
    // although they contain same property & value
    // so a test for equality will return false
    console.log("should be false: ", obja === objb);

    // on the other hand 'valuea' and 'valueb' are 
    // both value types, so an equality test will be true
    console.log("should be true: ", valuea === valueb);
```

to achieve what you want, you either have to have added the actual reference, as I did above, or loop through the array and compare by unique property of the objects.

Answer (score 4):

you can use find to returns the value of the this element

```
const array = [{a: 'b'}];
array.includes(array.find(el=>el.a==='b'));
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
const arr = [{a: 'b',b:'c'},{a: 'c'}]
console.log(arr.some(item => item.b === 'c'))
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate whats different in your solution and how it differs from other answers or how is it better.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can, if only so

```js
const arr = [{a:'a'},{a: 'b'}]
const serch = arr[1]
console.log(arr.includes(serch))
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use string comparisons on objects unless you first convert them to strings with...

```
JSON.stringify(TheObject)
```

So to loop through all objects in an array so as to prevent adding a duplicate object, you can use something like this...

```
let Bad=false;

ObjectArray.forEach(function(e){if(JSON.stringify(NewObject)===JSON.stringify(e)){Bad=true;}});

if(Bad){alert('This object already exists!');} else {ObjectArray.push(NewObject);}
```